# Filling in missing rows/columns in distance matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I've two distance matrices.. but either of them can have items missing, and they can be out of order -- for example:

matrix #1 (missing item c)

```
  a b d 
a 0 2 3 
b 2 0 4 
d 3 4 0
```

matrix #2 (missing item b, and items out of order)

```
  d c a
d 0 1 2 
c 1 0 1 
a 2 1 0
```

I want to find the difference between the matrices, while assuming that any missing items are 0. So, my resulting matrix should be:

```
  a b c d
a 0 2 1 1
b 2 0 0 4
c 1 0 0 1
d 1 4 1 0
```

What's the best way to go about this? Should I be sorting both matrices and then filling in missing columns/rows so that I can then just abs(m1-m2), or is there a way to use row/column headings to have them automatically "match up" when subtracting?

These matrices are 5000x5000 or so, and I'll have about a 1000 to do pairwise comparison on, so I'd rather take a hit on preprocessing the data if that will make each computation significantly faster.

Any hints or suggestions are welcome. I'm usually a non-R programmer, so an iterative solution that I would normally come up would take forever -- I'm hoping for the "R way" of doing things that will be significantly faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a names index ('Un1') which is the `union` of names of the first ('m1') and second ('m2') `matrix`.  Two new 0 matrices ('m1N', 'm2N') are created by specifying the dimensions and dim names based on 'Un1'. By row/column indexing, we change the 0 values in these matrices to the values in 'm1', 'm2', subtract and get the absolute.

```
Un1 <- sort(union(colnames(m1), colnames(m2)))
m1N <- matrix(0, ncol=length(Un1), nrow=length(Un1), dimnames=list(Un1, Un1))
m2N <- m1N
m1N[rownames(m1), colnames(m1)] <- m1
m2N[rownames(m2), colnames(m2)] <- m2
abs(m1N-m2N)
#  a b c d
#a 0 2 1 1
#b 2 0 0 4
#c 1 0 0 1
#d 1 4 1 0
```

#### Update

If we have several matrices with object names `m` followed by numbers, we can place them in a `list`.  We get the object names using `ls` and the values in a `list` with `mget`.  Loop through the `list` with `lapply` to get the column names, use `union` as `f` in `Reduce`, `sort` to get the `unique` elements.

```
lst <- mget(ls(pattern='m\\d+')) #change the pattern accordingly
Un1 <- sort(Reduce(union, lapply(lst, colnames)))
```

We can create another `list` with `matrix` of 0s.

```
lst1 <- lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) 
    matrix(0, ncol=length(Un1), nrow=length(Un1), dimnames=list(Un1, Un1)))
```

We can change the corresponding elements of 'lst1' using the row/column index of corresponding matrices of 'lst' using `Map`.

```
lst2 <- Map(function(x,y) {x[rownames(y), colnames(y)] <- y; x}, lst1, lst)
```

If we need pairwise difference, `combn` may be an option

```
lst3 <- combn(seq_along(lst2),2, FUN=function(x) 
                      list(abs(lst2[[x[1]]]-lst2[[x[2]]])))
names(lst3) <- combn(seq_along(lst2), 2, FUN=paste, collapse='_')
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! One follow-up question -- if I had a large vector of matrices, how can I get the first step to be the union of all colnames, without iterating through that vector?

Comment: @Stan Updated the post.  But, I am not sure how you want to get the difference when there are more 2 matrices.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be creating a distance matrix of matrices -- i.e. finding the difference between every pair of matrices and creating a matrix distance map. So, your suggestion with combn is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `match` (beginning is similar to @akrun):

```
func = function(cols, m)
{
    res = `dimnames<-`(m[match(cols,rownames(m)), match(cols,colnames(m))],
                       list(cols, cols))
    ifelse(is.na(res), 0, res)
}


cols = sort(union(colnames(m1), colnames(m2)))
abs(func(cols,m1) - func(cols,m2))
#  a b c d
#a 0 2 1 1
#b 2 0 0 4
#c 1 0 0 1
#d 1 4 1 0
```